# AngularJS : How can I use an object id to create a set of form fields

Tags: angularjs, forms

**edit:** I worked it out, I need to use [tray.id] instead of {{tray.id}}

I have an array of "trays" and I want to build a form to edit them, but I'm not sure how to set the ng-model for each tray so I can differentiate between them.

This does not work, angular doesn't like me putting {{tray.id}} into ng-model

```
<div ng-repeat="tray in formData.trayData">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="formData.trays.{{tray.id}}.name">Name:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tray.{{tray.id}}.name" ng-model="formData.trays.{{tray.id}}.name" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="formData.trays.{{tray.id}}.seal">Seal:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tray.{{tray.id}}.seal" ng-model="formData.trays.{{tray.id}}.sealed" placeholder="Seal">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

In my controller I setup formData using a json object from an API

```
$scope.formData.trayData = $scope.surgeryDetails.trays;
$scope.formData.trays = [];
```

And here is what I get from {{formdata.trayData}}

```
[{"id":8,"name":"Tray 1","seal":"Foo","status_id":9},{"id":9,"name":"Tray 2","seal":"Bar","status_id":9}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you figured the ngModel part out on your own.

However, I also just wanted to mention that you may not be getting what you are expecting when/if you go to handle validation using the `name` attribute.

There is currently a [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1404) in Angular that prevents dynamic element validation. The workaround is provided in the comments by Thinkscape, or [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hSMzWC?p=preview) is a plunker with the correct code. Here is the main part:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('ngModelDirective', function($delegate) {
      var ngModel = $delegate[0],
        controller = ngModel.controller;
      ngModel.controller = ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$injector',
        function(scope, element, attrs, $injector) {
          var $interpolate = $injector.get('$interpolate');
          attrs.$set('name', $interpolate(attrs.name || '')(scope));
          $injector.invoke(controller, this, {
            '$scope': scope,
            '$element': element,
            '$attrs': attrs
          });
        }
      ];
      return $delegate;
    });
    $provide.decorator('formDirective', function($delegate) {
      var form = $delegate[0],
        controller = form.controller;
      form.controller = ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$injector',
        function(scope, element, attrs, $injector) {
          var $interpolate = $injector.get('$interpolate');
          attrs.$set('name', $interpolate(attrs.name || attrs.ngForm || '')(scope));
          $injector.invoke(controller, this, {
            '$scope': scope,
            '$element': element,
            '$attrs': attrs
          });
        }
      ];
      return $delegate;
    });
  })
```